# Run automation only when editing a specific page

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I built an automation when I inserted values ​​into a form, but I wanted to add a trigger that when I added values ​​to a specific page, the action would execute. I currently have a trigger that the automation executes when I edit any range, and I want it to only execute when I edit a specific page

I managed to just execute when I edit any range

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet0") {
    e.source.toast("This is Sheet0");
  }
}
```